# Accessing members inside generic types

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a function which was earlier implemented as follows

```
export function insertItemInQueue(
  queueRef: RefObject<Partial<IMyRow>[]>,
  item: Partial<IMyRow>
) {
    console.log(item.ID)
    queueRef.current.push(item);
}
```

In order to use generics, I have changed it to

```
export function insertItemInQueue<ItemType>(
  queueRef: RefObject<ItemType[]>,
  item: ItemType
) {
     console.log(item.ID)
     queueRef.current.push(item);
}
```

However, I now get the TS error: **Property 'ID' does not exist on type 'ItemType'.**

I understand ItemType could be anything and may not always have ID as its member. How do we get around this?

I was able to get it to compile by using it as **item['ID'] as opposed to item.ID**. But I am not sure if this is fine? I feel it takes away the point of generics and has a hard dependency on the fact that whatever generic type is passed in must contain a member called ID, which is not really generic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enforce at compile-time that this function call should only accept types that have an `ID` property, you can define the generic type as extending from an object that contains an `ID` property, like this (if your ID is not a `number`, just adjust the example)

```js
function insertItemInQueue<ItemType extends { ID: number }>(
  queueRef: RefObject<ItemType[]>,
  item: ItemType
) {
    console.log(item.ID) // no more compiler error
    queueRef.current.push(item);
}
```

Then the compiler checks and enforces the types at call site

```js
insertItemInQueue(queue, { ID: 123 }) // OK
insertItemInQueue(queue, { ID: 123, a: 1, b: "Some text" }) // OK

insertItemInQueue(queue, { ID: null }) // Error: Type 'null' is not assignable to type number
insertItemInQueue(queue, { ID: undefined }) // Error: Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type number
insertItemInQueue(queue, { a: 1 }) // Error: not the right type because the ID property is missing
```